# Learning JavaScript: Lexical Versus Dynamic Scoping

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

So I was reading [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035534.do) book, following along with the code examples and running them using node console. In Chapter 7, paragraph 'Lexical Versus Dynamic Scoping', the author claims that the following code will result in an error:

```
const x = 3;
function f() {
    console.log(x); // this will work
    console.log(y); // this will cause a crash
}

const y = 3;
f();
```

This is due to the fact that (as the book reads)

> Scoping in JavaScript is lexical...

and

> Lexical scoping means whatever variables are in scope where you define a function from (as opposed to when you call it) are in scope in the function.

However this code runs just fine, and produces the following output:

> 3
>
> 3

I have searched for other examples of lexical scoping and what it means, but they all seem to suggest slightly different things from what the book says. So I am left wondering, is the explanation in the book completely wrong or am I missing something very basic?

Comment: Your code works - and the term you're looking for, I think, is Hoisting.

Comment: I think hoisting has little or nothing to do with this. The book also explains hoisting in a totally different paragraph. This example is supposed to be provided in order to understand lexical scoping.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted description…

> Lexical scoping means whatever variables are in scope where you define a function from (as opposed to when you call it) are in scope in the function.

… is correct.

The code example is wrong. The function `f` has access to any variable (or constant) that exists in the scope that it is declared in. What the book appears to get wrong is that constants can be added to that scope after the function has been declared.

Where the function is declared matters. When it is declared, not so much.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this is probably the most reasonable explanation, the book contains countless other minor mistakes so the author could have gotten that wrong as well... This seems as a major mistake to me and the book loses a lot of credibility and respect, assuming that this explanation holds true, since the author did not even run through his code examples to check if they are correct...

Answer (score 2):

The above code will work fine. However, this will fail.

```
const x = 3;
function f() {
    console.log(x); // this will work
    console.log(y); // this will cause a crash
}
f();
const y = 3;
```

That is because y is not yet declared or defined at the time of function invocation and

`x` is accessible because Scoping is lexical and function will access the `x` defined in global scope, if not found on local.

This can be understood by this example more clearly

```
function b(){
  console.log(v) //=> 1
} //lexically defined at global scope

function a(){
  var v = 2
  console.log(v) //=> 2
  b() //called in the scope of a()
}

var v = 1
a()
console.log(v) //=> 1
```

`console.log` in `b()` will give 1 because according to lexical global scope `v = 1`. But according to Dynamic Scope (created by `a()`) it should be 2, which is not the case.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, you are correct, if `f()` is **called before** `y` is declared, it will result in a `ReferenceError`. The book says though that **calling** `f()` **even after** `y` is declared should produce an error as well, because, according to the book, at the time `f()` was declared, `y` was not. This does not seem to hold true and is what baffles me.

Answer (score 1):

This book looks quite old - 11 years ago. The world is no longer the same. Now we see that JavaScript changes day after day. I think that we should not use any book produced since 2 years ago.

The problem you (and the book) mentioned is relating to another concept: strict mode. In ECMAScript 5, you can turn on this mode by adding "use strict" on top of your JavaScript file. So that, you would see some errors throw while they don't in regular mode. If you want to get the example works, you may need to find an old browser, IE8 or such - I'm not sure, then create a HTML file, then add your script to, then turn on strict mode, it may give you the same result as the author said.

Strict mode is no longer the case in JavaScript today - I would like to talk about ECMAScript 6, or ES6, or ECMAScript 2015. We simple don't need to care about strict mode while writing JavaScript now. I have many module on npmjs.org but none of them have "use strict" declaration at all.

Just my two cents: in programming, don't read old books, because everything changes so fast.

Comment: Hey, sorry my bad, I accidentally linked to the old version of the book. I am actually reading the third edition, published in 2016: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035534.do

Comment: ok, so I need to look at the script itself now. I think that there is no problem with it. Even the variable "y" has been declared after being referenced, but with "hoisting effect" in JavaScript, it should not cause any error as the author said.

Even in strict mode, because strict mode does not avoid hoisting.

However, using an variable before declaring it is a bad practice. The linters should be configured to notice developers about that.

Comment: the code runs perfectly fine, the problem is the book states that it shouldn't. Also I don't think hoisting applies to this example, `const`s and `let`s will result in an error if they are used before they are declared, in comparison to `var`s.